# Найти разность между значениями ключей в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dict, broadcasting

Дан словарь, где разным ключам соответствуют векторы разного размера. Необходимо найти разность между каждым значением одного ключа и каждым значением остальных. Структура словарей меняется в зависимости от входящего датасета.Т.е. алгоритм должен работать с разными размерами значений. Если более точно, то в словаре хранятся индексы точек, которые являются центроидами, а значения векторов - индексы точек, которые относятся к этому кластеру. Если эта информация как-то поможет:) 
Пыталась использовать broadcasting. На игрушечном примере сработало, а на реальном нет.

```
in: a = [5, 6, 6, 6, 7]
b = [4,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,5,2,46]
Centroids  = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    Centroids[i].append(j)
Centroids
out: defaultdict(list, {5: [4], 6: [3, 4, 5], 7: [6]})
in: k = []
for i in list(Centroids.values()):
    k.append(np.array(i))
print(np.array(k)) 
a = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        a.append(k[i] - k[j])
print(a)
out: [array([4]) array([3, 4, 5]) array([6])]
[array([0]), array([ 1,  0, -1]), array([-2]), array([-1,  0,  1]), array([0, 0, 0]), array([-3, -2, -1]), array([2]), array([3, 2, 1]), array([0])]
```

Это пример, который не сработал:

```
 in: k = centers(data)
    out: [array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 75]), 
    array([21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]), 
    array([41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 73, 74]), 
    array([59, 60, 63, 66]), 
    array([61, 62])]
 in: a = []
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            a.append(k[i] - k[j])
```

Вылеталет ошибка:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (29,) (20,)
```

Вопрос в том, **как можно найти эту разность?** Выше я привела свои неудачные попытки. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какую разность вы пытаетесь посчитать? Между индексами точек? Между точками - это расстояние? Или что-то ещё?

Comment: @MaxU у меня сложность в любых операциях между значениями. Вопрос в том, как просто найти в данном случае разность между значениями ключей. {a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5]}. Найти [1-4, 1-5, 2-4, 2-5, 3-4, 3-5].

Answer (score 3):

Ответ на вопрос из комментария:

> Вопрос в том, как просто найти в данном случае разность между
>   значениями ключей. `{a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5]}`. Найти `[1-4, 1-5, 2-4,
>   2-5, 3-4, 3-5]`.

можно воспользоваться Numpy `broadcasting`:

```
In [299]: a = np.array([1,2,3])

In [300]: b = np.array([4, 5])

In [301]: (a[:, None] - b).ravel()
Out[301]: array([-3, -4, -2, -3, -1, -2])
```

в виде 2D массива:

```
In [302]: (a[:, None] - b)
Out[302]:
array([[-3, -4],
       [-2, -3],
       [-1, -2]])
```